# Is Interactive Services Detection a legitimate message from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have Windows 7 running in a VM on my Ubuntu PC, for when I occasionally need to do something on Windows. Today this message appeared, but I'm a little skeptical that it is actually from Windows.

Notice that instead of saying it might "need information **from** you" it says "need information **form** you".

[image: Interactive Services Detection - Program is trying to display a message]

Comment: In short, there are programs running in the background ("services"). They normally cannot show anything on your screen. When you click "view the message", you switch to another desktop where you can temporarily interact with the program. Once you're done, you'll go back to your own desktop. It's perfectly fine, although unusual.

Comment: The background program (service) you're running has a bug. It is doing something it was never supposed to be doing, and something that was *officially* broken by Microsoft over a decade ago. Look for an updated version of it, or file a bug report with the vendor of the software. And yeah, that spelling error is craziness. No idea how that ever got past Microsoft's QA.

Comment: @CodyGray To be fair, if the service was written pre-Vista, it's not a bug, that's just what services did at the time.

Comment: Spelling errors are common even in genuine Windows messages (in particular in translated versions - the German messages are often horrible)

Comment: FYI Alt+PrintScreen captures the current active window so you don't have to crop with ugly artifacts around like that. Snipping tool also have an option to capture current window

Comment: No, @isanae, it's still a bug. You weren't supposed to be doing that prior to Vista, either. It just happened to "work" because of the inherently weaker security model. In Windows NT, services were *never* meant to display interactive UI.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The Interactive Services Detection message is meant for errors that happen in service context of the desktop session when a service tries to interact with the legacy desktop (desktops with session 0). This is a mitigation feature of the Windows environment post-Vista. Currently Windows employs session 0 isolation (now the desktop of the first user to log in is run in session 1 instead).

Clicking on view message should bring you to session 0's desktop where you can deal with the (probably an error of some kind) message further.

For a more expansive explanation see MSDN blog posts by Pat Altimore on it:

- [What is Interactive Services Detection and Why is it Blinking at Me?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me/)
- [Troubleshooting Interactive Services Detection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2011/03/14/troubleshooting-interactive-services-detection/)

If you are ***really paranoid*** like me ;P, disconnect the VM from the internet and then proceed. You can even go get a set of Sysinternals Suite from Microsoft [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) and use the modules:

- `procexp` - more detailed version of task manager for seeing exactly whats going on where
- `tcpview` - see what connections are being attempted, from where, and to whom

This should give you ample information to decide whether this is a malicious exploit gone wrong, or a harmless bug on the system. It's more than likely just a harmless error, but I'll never tell someone to be less cautious.

UPDATE:

As for the spelling error, I took your image and did a reverse google image search. This spelling error appears in a lot of screenshots of this message. It makes my stomach turn as I'm sure it does you, but just be careful and diligent in debugging it and you should be ok. But to be fair, the spelling error also appears in the [screenshot on Microsoft's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me/) I linked earlier too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and update. I've been conditioned to never trust anything with bad grammar and/or spelling, which was why I was alarmed by this. Extreme paranoia makes me want to just nuke the VM and create another one. :-)

Comment: I'm exactly the same. To think of how many VMs I've nuked from orbit just because they said one little thing wrong... I just realized im an evil vm master :(